# What are the efficient query for mongodb if value exist on array then don't update and return the error that id already exist

Tags: mongodb

I have an entry stored on my collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d416c595f19962ff0680dbc"),
    "data" : {
        "a" : 6,
        "b" : [ 
            "5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a6"
        ]
    },
    "image" : "123.jpg",
    "hyperlinks" : "google.com",
    "expirydate" : ISODate("2019-08-27T06:10:35.074Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2019-07-31T10:24:25.311Z"),
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2019-07-31T10:24:25.311Z"),
    "__v" : 0
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d416c595f19962ff0680dbd"),
    "data" : {
        "a" : 90,
        "b" : [ 
            "5c35f04c4e92b8337885d9a7"
        ]
    },
    "image" : "456.jpg",
    "hyperlinks" : "google.com",
    "expirydate" : ISODate("2019-08-27T06:10:35.074Z"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2019-07-31T10:24:25.311Z"),
    "lastmodified" : ISODate("2019-07-31T10:24:25.311Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I have to write the query for push userid on `b array` which is under data object and increment the `a counter` which is also under `data object`.

For that, I wrote the Code i.e

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5d416c595f19962ff0680dbd")},
 {$inc: {'data.a': 1}, $push: {'data.b': '124sdff54f5s4fg5'}}
)
```

I also want to check that if that id exist on array then return the response that following id exist, so for that I wrote extra query which will check and if id exist then return the error response that following id exist,

My question is that any single query will do this? Like I don't want to write Two Queries for single task.

Any help is really appreciated for that

Comment: When there is nothing new is inserted into `data.b`, having `$inc: {'data.a': 1}` OK? If you only had `$addToSet` for insertion into `data.b`, you could've check the `modifiedCount` field in the response. If the value is `0` that means the value was already in the array.

Comment: I think what you want is only update the document by  appending the value into the array if it doesn't exist. In which case you should check that that in filter.

Comment: You could then check `nModified` value and raise/throw an exception in you code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more check in the update query on "data.b". Following would be the query:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: ObjectId("5d416c595f19962ff0680dbd"),
        "data.b":{
            $ne: "124sdff54f5s4fg5"
        }
    },
    {
        $inc: {'data.a': 1}, 
        $push: {'data.b': '124sdff54f5s4fg5'}
    }
)
```

For duplicate entry, you would get the following response:

```
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 }
```

If matched count is 0, you can show the error that the id already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the operator `$addToSet` to check if the element already exits in the array.

```
db.collection.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("5d416c595f19962ff0680dbd")},
 {$inc: {'data.a': 1}, $addToSet: {'data.b': '124sdff54f5s4fg5'}}
)
```

Comment: $addToSet would eliminate adding duplicate value in array but still $inc would perform, thus the modified count would not be 0.